# detect which item is selected by the hand pointer (not mouse) in listbox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect-v2

is there any similar way to detect which item in a listBox wpf had been selected by kinect v2 hand pointer?
I tried to use selected trigger on listbox but always get and error that says:  'ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'Selected' and no extension method 'Selected' accepting a first argument of type 'ListBox'

```
                    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemTemplate11}" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" Selected="listBox_Selected">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                </ListBox>


public partial class MainWindow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MainWindow"/> class. 
    /// </summary>
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        KinectRegion.SetKinectRegion(this, kinectRegion);

        App app = ((App)Application.Current);
        app.KinectRegion = kinectRegion;

        // Use the default sensor
        this.kinectRegion.KinectSensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();

    }

    private void listBox_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(listBox.SelectedIndex.ToString());
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh? ListBox has a SelectionChanged event and a SelectedItem property. Selected is an event on ListBoxItem. Trap the SelectionChanged event on the ListBox itself.

Comment: thanks for answering, I use selectionchanged but when using hand pointer after first selection it freezes like this: https://ibb.co/iBDo8a